# Android Sqlite Oprationation

Tags: java, android, database, android-sqlite, android-cursoradapter

I want perform a search operation.I am using CursorAdapter to show data from database.Here is my code

DBHelper

```
public Cursor fetchDataByName(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select  ABSTRACTS_ITEM._id,ABSTRACTS_ITEM.TITLE,ABSTRACTS_ITEM.TOPIC, "
                + "ABSTRACTS_ITEM.TYPE,ABSTRACTS_ITEM.TEXT"
                + "ABSTRACT_KEY_WORDS.KEYWORDS "
                + "from ABSTRACTS_ITEM,ABSTRACT_KEY_WORDS "
                + "where ABSTRACTS_ITEM._id = ABSTRACT_KEY_WORDS._id "
                + "and ABSTRACT_KEY_WORDS.KEYWORDS like '%" + string + "%'"
                + "or ABSTRACTS_ITEM.TITLE like '%" + string + "%'", null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Inside Activity

```
cursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return dbHelper.fetchDataByName(constraint.toString());
            }
        });
```

Previously, I can search data only with `Title`. Now, I want search data according to `Title or keyword`. As you can see my query, tried with that. But, it's not working.Because, it shows nothing.

Comment: @Nambari Sorry, I didn't get you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `,` comma and you need to group your OR condition in brackets because `AND` has a higher precedence.

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select ABSTRACTS_ITEM._id, "
        + "ABSTRACTS_ITEM.TITLE, ABSTRACTS_ITEM.TOPIC, "
        + "ABSTRACTS_ITEM.TYPE, ABSTRACTS_ITEM.TEXT, " // <-- Comma needed
        + "ABSTRACT_KEY_WORDS.KEYWORDS "
        + "from ABSTRACTS_ITEM,ABSTRACT_KEY_WORDS "
        + "where ABSTRACTS_ITEM._id = ABSTRACT_KEY_WORDS._id "
          // Group the OR condition with "()"; AND has higher precedence
        + "and (ABSTRACT_KEY_WORDS.KEYWORDS like '%" + string + "%' "
        + "or ABSTRACTS_ITEM.TITLE like '%" + string + "%')", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a simple precedence problem, AND in SQL has a higher precedence than OR. I think you want your SQL to look more like this:

```
where ABSTRACTS_ITEM._id = ABSTRACT_KEY_WORDS._id
  and (
        ABSTRACT_KEY_WORDS.KEYWORDS like '%' || ? || '%'
     or ABSTRACTS_ITEM.TITLE like '%' || ? || '%'
  )
```

I've also switched to placeholders since using string concatenation to build SQL is far too 1999 for me. This means that you'll want to use the [`rawQuery(String sql, String\[\] selectionArgs)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) version of `rawQuery`.